# Find one or more components within f:facet - does it work as designed?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have on my page a custom component with a Facet inside

```
<jtcomp:blockUI ...>
   <f:facet name="events">
      <f:param name="filtering" value="true"/>
      <f:param name="sorting" value="true"/>
      <f:param name="paging" value="true"/>
   </f:facet>
   ...
</jtcomp:blockUI>
```

In the renderer class I intend to gather all UIParameter (f:param). At first I get the facet as follows

```
UIComponent facet = blockUI.getFacet("events");
```

Well. Now I thought I can call facet.getChildren() and iterate then over all childs. But I have debugged and figured out I can only do it if f:facet contains more than one f:param components. If it only has one f:param like this

```
<jtcomp:blockUI ...>
   <f:facet name="events">
      <f:param name="filtering" value="true"/>
   </f:facet>
   ...
</jtcomp:blockUI>
```

the call above delivers already this component. I mean, facet is an UIParameter. Therefore, the entire logic looks like

```
// collect all f:param
List<UIParameter> uiParams = new ArrayList<UIParameter>();
if (facet instanceof UIParameter) {
  // f:facet has one child and that's f:param
  uiParams.add((UIParameter) facet);
} else if (facet != null && facet.getChildren() != null) {
  // f:facet has no or more than one child
  for (UIComponent kid : facet.getChildren()) {
     if (kid instanceof UIParameter) {
        uiParams.add((UIParameter) kid);
     }
  }
}
```

Is it an expected JSF behavior or just a Mojarra bug (I'm using Mojarra 2.1.0-b02)? I know, that before JSF2 only one component was allowed to be inside of f:facet. Maybe they still check it and don't instantiate FacetsMap if only one child component is available. Instead of FacetsMap containing all child components there is then the child component self bound as a facet to the parent component.

What do you think? I could nothing find in the JSF specification. Thanks in advance for your replies!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, found the answer in the method addComponent from ComponentSupport. java

```
/**
* Add the child component to the parent. If the parent is a facet,
* check to see whether the facet is already defined. If it is, wrap the existing component
* in a panel group, if it's not already, then add the child to the panel group.
* If the facet does not yet exist, make the child the facet.
*/
public static void addComponent(FaceletContext ctx, UIComponent parent, UIComponent child)
```

All facets children are included into a UIPanel automatically, so that my code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where it is specified but I found a comment in the official Java EE tutorial.

From the [Java EE 6 tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnarz/index.html) (including JavaServer Faces 2.0):

> Facets can have only one child, so an
>   h:panelGroup tag is needed if you want
>   to group more than one component
>   within an f:facet

Maybe wrapping your params inside an `h:panelGroup` will help you.

Comment: Hi Matt. Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure if JSF2 has still this limitation. I have working examples where I have more than one component inside of f:facet. But even if it's still true, why does the call facet.getChildren() returns an empty collection if we have only one component? That's why I check "facet instanceof UIParameter" (see my code above).The strange thing I wanted to point to is the return value of facet.getChildren(). The collection containes all components if there are more than one and nothing (empty) is there is only one component.

Comment: Hi Oleg, yes, I think this limitation remains. I can have more than one component inside f:facet but only one _direct_ child, e.g. a panelGroup that wraps the other.

Comment: Hi Matt. Maybe, but with facet.getChildren() (my code above) I get all direct children, not only one. In my case there are 3 children. And I get nothing if there is only one diret child component. Is it not strange?